# toolbar text setting to class="center",but in android browser see in the left

Tags: android, html, css, onsen-ui

I download the Tab Bar Template (http://onsen.io/project-templates/gen/onsenui-tab-bar.zip)
IOS and my pc chrome no problem,the toolbar text in center,
but my android phone(new moto x 5.0 and meizu mx4 4.4.4 )  see the toolbar text in the left.
is it bug?
Thx for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbdKC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in Onsen UI docs: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-toolbar.html#attributes

Just use the attribute `fixed-style` and it will always display it in the center regardless the platform.

Comment: @Lemon If it was useful for you, please, consider marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!